# Get most rescent 10 records using angular fire from firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to get most rescent 10 records using angular fire. Here is the object hierarchy stored in firebase.

[image]
This is how i am handling customer list in my service

```
            customersRef.$loaded()
            .then(function(list) {
                deferred.resolve(list);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
          return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Q. How do i change this to make the list order by CreatedAt and i only need to get most rescent 10 customers.

I tried list.$ref().orderByChild('CreatedAt') but it fails.

Comment: This should work: `$firebaseArray(customersRef.$ref().orderByChild('CreatedAt').limitToFirst(10))`. This is probably what you tried, but the `$firebaseArray` is missing in the snippet you provided. If you can't get it to work, can you provide a reproduction of the problem in a jsfiddle/jsbin/plunker?

Comment: Thanks i was waiting for someone to reply :) i will try this and if it works will let you know so that you can post it as an answer.

Comment: It worked, but it works for 'FirstName' and 'LastName', For some reasons it is not working for 'CreatedeAt' field. I double checked the spelling, its correct. I am assuming something is wrong with my data, i tried both ways CreatedAt: 1427644485338  AND CreatedAt:"1427644485338"

Comment: For 'FirstName' and 'LastName' it works perfectly. But when i use 'CreatedAt' its not showing the most recent record on top ? I was looking at the documentation and it looks like it orders records in ASC mode. I want them in DSC mode to get the most rescent on top. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data  . I will see if i can create a jsfiddle.

Comment: There is no descending operator in Firebase. Instead, you can *either* grab the last N records that you need and reverse them in memory *or* add a field that has a value range for your needs, e.g. `-1 * Date.now()*.